# Why i am not able to Create the another dialog from one dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, dialog, android-dialog

In My application i need to open one dialog. And on press of button on that dialog i want to open another dialog and do some action.
Both the dialog are custom dialog.
But while i do that i am not able to create the dialog...

See below code:

```
twsbiImageDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
            twsbiImageDialog.setContentView(R.layout.twsbi_logo_dialog);
            twsbiImageDialog.setCancelable(true);

            // To visit Website ===================================
            Button visitWebsiteButton = (Button) twsbiImageDialog.findViewById(R.id.visitWebsiteButton);
            visitWebsiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    twsbiImageDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent in = new Intent(FingerPaint.this,GoogleSite.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });

            // For About ===================================
            Button aboutButton = (Button) twsbiImageDialog.findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
            aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    twsbiImageDialog.dismiss();
                    //System.out.println("I Am here before Dialog");
                    aboutDialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(),R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                    aboutDialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
                    aboutDialog.setCancelable(true);

                     Button okButton = (Button) aboutDialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
                     okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                            aboutDialog.dismiss();
                         }
                     });
                     aboutDialog.show();
                    //openAboutDialog();

                }

            });
            twsbiImageDialog.show();
```

And If i do like that i got the error like below:

```
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.project.twsbi.FingerPaint$8.onClick(FingerPaint.java:546)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-05 11:43:21.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you getting some kind of exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current activity as context:

```
aboutDialog = new Dialog(ActivityName.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: No problem iDroid Explorer! It would be nice if you accepted the answer as correct, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think dont use **getApplicationContext()** in your button second dialog open code. Use the context of this page.

Try this, It may be help you.

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer as correct. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Context context;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout......);

        context = this;
    }
```

Dialog inside dialog:

```
    aboutDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);             
            aboutDialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);        
            aboutDialog.setCancelable(true);
```